# A much faster lagrange interpolation MATLAB code

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

The following code is a simple lagrange interpolation. I have two vectors `k` and `kt` for which I want to do the math. I put all the answers in a matrix `H` at the end. However when I have to do this for lots of `k`s and `kt`s, my code runs with much time that I expect.

How can this code rewritten in a faster way?

```
N = 1:length(kt);
H = zeros(length(kt),length(k));
for m = 1:length(k)
    for j = 1:length(kt)
        h = 1;
        index = find(N ~= j);
        for jj = 1:length(index)
            h = h*(k(m)-kt(index(jj)))./(kt(j)-kt(index(jj)));
        end
        H(j,m) = h;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) to avoid those loops, like so -

```
kt3D = permute(kt(:),[3 2 1]);
D = bsxfun(@rdivide,bsxfun(@minus,k(:),kt3D),bsxfun(@minus,kt(:).',kt3D)); %//'
D(:,1:numel(k):numel(kt)*numel(kt)) = 1;
Hout = prod(D,3).'; %//'
```

Comment: Nice answer! I really like the permute + bsxfun answers, because: 1. They are really neat, and efficient. 2. It forces people to understand how MATLAB works (vectorization and how it handles matrices). It's almost impossible to just copy-paste, as people that don't understand it will have a really hard time adapting it to other problems (even if they're almost identical). Note: I'm not trying to say that it's a good thing that OP doesn't necessarily understand, I mean it's a good thing that OP is forced to understand =)

Comment: @StewieGriffin Specially how the indexing works in MATLAB and how elements could be moved around across various dimensions, which involves a major learning curve. Although, one could always complain about readability with solutions like these :)

Comment: @Divakar  "readability" -- have you *seen*  the "obfuscated C"  code competitions?  :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Damit! There are such competitions in C, like on `SO`? MATLAB needs such things too!! ;)

Comment: @Divakar This solution doesn't look very fast. for `kt = 1:100;`, `yt = kt.*kt;` and `k  = 1:1000;` it took 2 seconds on my machine to run the code 3 times. But also this is the fault of the original algorithm for `H`, because it wastes a lot of time for computing over and over again the same thing.

Comment: @CST-Link Well, I compared it against OP's code and seems to be much faster with that input. On my machine - With `bsxfun` : `0.084707 s`. With OP's code : `1.092811 s`. Unless I am doing something different from your benchmarking procedure.

Comment: @Divakar According to the profiling I've done (on my machine), the issue is not the `bsxfun` call (0.05s) but the `prod` call (0.71). A total of 0.76 seconds run time in profiler, compared to 4.1 seconds for the original code. But as I remember, we had already lots of talking about the wild differences in performance between our software/machines. Either mine is dumb, or yours is magic. :-)

Comment: @CST-Link Well with that input, I am seeing `bsxfun(@rdivide,bsxfun(@minus,k(:),kt3D),bsxfun(@minus,kt(:).',kt3D))` taking `0.06 secs`, while ` prod(D,3).'` getting at `0.03 secs` when profiled with profiler. I am not using `timeit` though, so that might be bringing in the unwanted magic with my benchmarking. Nevertheless, OP's datasizes might be different, so.. whatever works I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the interpolation nodes are (`kt`, `yt`), how about going directly for interpolation, and skipping the Lagrange form entirely? i.e. for the test case:

```
%'Test case'
kt = 1:10;
yt = kt.*kt.*(0.9 + 0.1*rand(size(kt)));
k  = 1.5:0.01:9.5;
```

the calculations would be:

```
%'Put data in convenient shape'
kt = kt(:);
yt = yt(:);
k  = k (:);

%'Interpolate in the points k based on points kt'
tic;
y = polyval(vander(kt)\yt, k);
toc;
```

as seen on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Constructing_the_interpolation_polynomial).

The `vander(kt)\yt` is the *definition* of the interpolation polynomial coefficients, expressed in terms of Vandermonde matrix. Mathematically speaking, the Lagrange interpolation will return *exactly* the same polynomial as the direct definition (in fact *all* polynomial interpolation methods will give essentially the same polynomial); the form is different though, because Lagrange interpolation avoids solving the linear system for the unknown polynomial coefficients.

Compared to the code that you posted:

- is way simpler;
- can be easily scaled for very large or very small values of `kt` and `yt` in order to control the errors (one can "normalize" the values, and scale back the results);
- is approx 75 times faster for the test case above (tested on MATLAB 2012a, 3Gb RAM, i5) while it already calculates the interpolated values.

Comment: Would be helpful to explain the `vander` function and how it applies here.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @CST-Link I have to use the lagrange interpolation, the `H` matrix was the weights I need to do the lagrange interpolation. Does your solution use the lagrange interpolation?  whats the `vander` function's job?

Comment: @CST-Link actually, I have another problem for which I need the matrix `H`. I have to compute a 2D lagrange interpolation so I compute the `H` matrix for two direction separately and then using a tensor product I obtain the 2D weights and interpolate the 2D matrix of `yt`.

Comment: @shalooshaloo **1)** `vander` gives you the Vandermonde matrix associated to a vector. Why it is used is explained in the Wikipedia link. **2)** All polynomial interpolation algorithms will give you the same result (i.e. the same polynomial), but with various forms. Lagrange form of the interpolation polynomial avoids solving a linear system. However, MATLAB is quite good at solving those, so I used this. **3)** I suppose that any kind of polynomial interpolation is okay, as long as is fast and accurate, so I don't understand why the *need* to use Lagrange. Is this homework?

Comment: @shalooshaloo Oh, I see. So you need to interpolate in 2D. Don't want to sound patronizing (and I apologize if I do) but aren't the standard MATLAB interpolation functions fast/accurate enough? I would look at `interp2` for example.

Comment: @CST-Link No it is not a homework. I am working on a paper and it says that the lagrange polynomial using chebyshev nodes do what they wants.

Answer (score 0):

(I chose to post a new answer instead of modifying the old one. I think is a good idea to keep them separated).

Better algorithmic complexity usually beats faster hardware or optimized libraries for big problem sizes. The [baricentric form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial#Barycentric_interpolation) of the Lagrange interpolation polynomial ensures a complexity *O*(*nt*×*n*) for the calculation of the *nt*×*n* matrix `H`, while your algorithm is *O*(*nt*<sup>2</sup>×*n*).

A `for`-based implementation for the usual test case:

```
%'Test case'
kt = 1:10;
yt = kt.*kt;
k  = 1.5:0.01:9.5;
```

would be:

```
%'Put data in convenient shape'
kt = kt(:);
yt = yt(:);
k  = k (:);

%'Baricentric weights'
w = zeros(numel(kt), 1);
for nt = 1:numel(kt)
        u     = kt(nt) - kt;
        w(nt) = 1/prod(u(u~=0));
end;

%'Lagrange interpolant coefficients'
H = zeros(numel(kt), numel(k));
for n = 1:numel(k)
        d      = k(n) - kt;
        H(:,n) = prod(d)*w./d;
end;
H(isnan(H)) = 1;
```

with the interpolated values:

```
%'Interpolate on nodes k and test'
y = transpose(transpose(yt)*H);
figure();
plot(k,y);
```

Comment: yes I have seen the barycenteric form. However, when you have 2 dimension, for example `kt1` and `kt2`, you will have two matrices `H1` and `H2`, and for doing the interpolation you have two do a tensor product each column(or row) of `H1` with `H2` so you have another for loop. These for loops when you have many of `k1` and `k2` vectors will be a problem

Comment: @shalooshaloo Merge the k1 and k2 vectors, apply the algorithm for all of them, then split the interpolated values by the length of the original vectors. On another hand, how many folds an improvement of speed you would consider to be a decent performance? And what are the benchmarks on your machine for the code that is already provided?

Comment: @shalooshaloo The idea is that one needs information to decide what to optimize. The problem changes for example when `kn` and `k` have roughly the same size, as compared to the case when `kn` has far fewer elements, as compared to the case where `k` has far fewer elements. All these recommend different strategies for optimization. All this information might be useful, and should be stated beforehand.